# input read through scan briefly appears and then resets instantly. How do I fix this?

Tags: javascript, html

I can't get this code block to work properly:

```
    <script>
        function Message(){
            document.getElementById("sname").innerHTML = document.getElementById("name").value;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td style="width:20%">User Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="name" name="name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="password"/></td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:right">
                    <input type="submit" onclick="Message()"/>
                </td>
            </tr>   
        </table>     
    </form>
    <div>
        <p>Hi <span id="sname">0</span></p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: That's a submit button.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
</head>
 <body>
<form onsubmit="event.preventDefault();">
    <table>
            <tr>
                <td style="width:20%">User Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="name" name="name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="password"/></td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:right">
                    <input type="submit" onclick="Message()"/>
                </td>
            </tr>   
    </table>     
</form>
<div>
<p>Hi <span id="sname">0</span></p>
</div>

<script>
function Message(){ document.getElementById("sname").innerHTML =     document.getElementById("name").value;  return false;}

 </script>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a submit button. Make `type='button'` instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution #1**

```js
function Message(){
event.preventDefault(); 
document.getElementById("sname").innerHTML = document.getElementById("name").value;
}
```

```html
<form>
        <table>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:20%">User Name:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="name" name="name" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="password"/></td></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:right">
                        <input type="submit" onclick="Message()"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>   
        </table>     
    </form>
    <div>
    <p>Hi <span id="sname">0</span></p>
  </div>
```

**Solution #2 you can just use button instead of input.**

```js
function Message(){
document.getElementById("sname").innerHTML = document.getElementById("name").value;
}
```

```html
<form>
        <table>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:20%">User Name:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="name" name="name" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="password"/></td></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:right">
                        <button type="button" onclick="Message()"/>Click me</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>   
        </table>     
    </form>
    <div>
    <p>Hi <span id="sname">0</span></p>
    </div>
```

Hope it helps!